# Delete consecutive empty rows in R

Tags: r, missing-data, data-manipulation

`df` presents possible name matches. Each pair of matches should be divided by an empty row. However, in some cases my output includes several empty rows between the matching pairs:

```
> df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,NA,3,4,NA,NA,NA,5,6,NA), name = c("john jones", "john joners", 
                   NA, "clara prat", "klara prat", NA, NA, NA, "alan turing", "allan turing", 
                   NA), stringsAsFactors = F)
> df
   id         name
1   1   john jones
2   2  john joners
3  NA         <NA>
4   3   clara prat
5   4   klara prat
6  NA         <NA>
7  NA         <NA>
8  NA         <NA>
9   5  alan turing
10  6 allan turing
11 NA         <NA>
```

The desired output is:

```
> df
   id         name
1   1   john jones
2   2  john joners
3  NA         <NA>
4   3   clara prat
5   4   klara prat
6  NA         <NA>
7   5  alan turing
8   6 allan turing
9  NA         <NA>
```

I can do this with a for loop, which I understand is less than optimal.

Comment: What have you tried, and what is the desired result?  Do you just want the same df without rows 7 and 8?

Comment: What is the final output that you want? What if only a single row has NAs, whereas surrounding rows do not? What if one of the variables in a row is NA, but other variables are not? Please show your desired output based on the example.

Comment: Added desired output. I expect there to be empty rows in between every pair of full rows. By design, a row is either fully complete or fully empty. Hope this makes the question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach using `rle` to look for runs of missing

```
miss <- rowSums(is.na(df))

# get runs of missing 
r <- rle(miss)
r$values <- seq_along(r$values)

# subset data, removing rows when all columns are missing 
# and rows sequentially missing
df[!(miss == ncol(df) & duplicated(inverse.rle(r))), ]
#   id         name
# 1   1   john jones
# 2   2  john joners
# 3  NA         <NA>
# 4   3   clara prat
# 5   4   klara prat
# 6  NA         <NA>
# 9   5  alan turing
# 10  6 allan turing
# 11 NA         <NA>
```

As mentioned by Akrun, you can use `data.table::rleid` to avoid some of the explicit `rle` calculations

```
df[!(rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df) & duplicated(data.table::rleid(is.na(df[[1]])))) , ]
```

Comment: I was also thinking about `rle`.  This looks nice.

Comment: cheers, Akrun: I  still think im missing a trick to simplify it. You can probably come up with a nice data.table version

Comment: You can also try with `rleid`, but I have some other headache problem to solve.

Comment: haha, stop doing so much then!! (my naive dt approach: `dt <- as.data.table(df) ; 
dt[!(rowSums(is.na(dt)) == ncol(dt) & duplicated(dt[ , rleid(is.na(id))])) , ]`

Comment: thanks user20650 and @akrun for the suggestions. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this helps

```
v1 <- rowSums(!is.na(df))
df[unlist(lapply(split(seq_along(v1),
     cumsum(c(1, diff(!v1))<0)), function(i) 
                    i[seq(which.max(v1[i]==0))])),]
#   id         name
#1   1   john jones
#2   2  john joners
#3  NA         <NA>
#4   3   clara prat
#5   4   klara prat
#6  NA         <NA>
#9   5  alan turing
#10  6 allan turing
#11 NA         <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `IRanges` package.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,NA,3,4,NA,NA,NA,5,6,NA), name = c("john jones", "john joners", 
                  NA, "clara prat", "klara prat", NA, NA, NA, "alan turing", "allan turing", 
                                         NA), stringsAsFactors = F)

library(IRanges)
na.rs <- which(is.na(df$id) & is.na(df$name))
na.rs.re <- reduce(IRanges(na.rs, na.rs))
na.rs.rm <- na.rs.re[width(na.rs.re)>1]
start(na.rs.rm) <- start(na.rs.rm) + 1

df[-as.integer(na.rs.rm), ]
#    id         name
# 1   1   john jones
# 2   2  john joners
# 3  NA         <NA>
# 4   3   clara prat
# 5   4   klara prat
# 6  NA         <NA>
# 9   5  alan turing
# 10  6 allan turing
# 11 NA         <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely not the best solution but easy to follow..

```
miss <- rowSums(is.na(df))
r <- sum(rle(miss)[[2]])

 for(i in 2:length(df$id)){
  while(is.na(df$id[i-1]) & is.na(df$id[i])){
   df <- df[-(i),] 
  if(sum(is.na(df$id)) == r) break
  }
 }
```